# I was practicing a way to loop numbers to create a times table but the loop only runs one time

Tags: javascript, html

I am practicing creating a function that loops whatever number I put into the input into a times table. I used a for loop to achieve this but I ran into an issue. My for loop only runs one time and it only get my input * 10 for some reason. Can someone please help. Thank you.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var inputNumber = document.querySelector(".input-field").value;
    inputNumber = parseInt(inputNumber);

    if (isNaN(inputNumber) || inputNumber == "" || inputNumber == null) {
        document.querySelector(".output h1").innerHTML = "Please enter a number!";
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            let product = inputNumber * i;
            document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = "<br>" + inputNumber + " * " + i + " = " + product + "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with relevant HTML to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you update the HTML on every iteration. However, I think you want to expand the innerHTML to include all elements?

I would look into creating html elements in javascripts and adding them in html like this (draft, untested):

```
const element = document.createElement("div")
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    let product = inputNumer * i;
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${inputNumer} ${product}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please study this. It is using recommended event listener and a map

```js
const arr = [...Array(11).keys()].slice(1); // numbers from 1 to 10
const h1 = document.querySelector("#output h1"),
  result = document.getElementById("result"),
  inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");
inputField.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const inputNumber = +this.value;
  console.log(inputNumber)
  h1.classList.toggle("hide", inputNumber); // keep hide if ok number
  result.innerHTML = inputNumber ? arr.map(i => `${inputNumber} * ${i} = ${inputNumber*i}`).join(`<br/>`) : "";
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputField" class=".input-field" />
<hr/>
<div id="output">
  <h1 class="error hide">Please enter a number!</h1>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</div>
```